# How can I convert data type in multiple field of Objects in JS

Tags: javascript, json

I want convert multi typeof property of my object

```
{
  "code": "00001",
  "displayOrder": "1",
  "name": "Hello",
  "version": "0",
  "isActive": "true",
  "createdAt": "2021-08-11T04:43:07.786Z",
  "updatedAt": "2021-08-11T04:43:07.786Z"
}
```

My Dto:

```
{
  "code": string,
  "displayOrder": number,
  "name": string,
  "version": number,
  "isActive": boolean,
  "createdAt": Date,
  "updatedAt": Date
}
```

How can I get

```
{
  "code": "00001",
  "displayOrder": 1,
  "name": "Hello",
  "version": 0,
  "isActive": true,
  "createdAt": 2021-08-11T04:43:07.786Z,
  "updatedAt": 2021-08-11T04:43:07.786Z
}
```

Pls help me

> {
> "code": "00001",
> "displayOrder": 1,
> "name": "Hello",
> "version": 0,
> "isActive": true,
> "createdAt": 2021-08-11T04:43:07.786Z,
> "updatedAt": 2021-08-11T04:43:07.786Z
> }

Answer (score 1):

You can set a function to convert type.

Like this:

```js
var originData = {
  "code": "00001",
  "displayOrder": "1",
  "name": "Hello",
  "version": "0",
  "isActive": "true",
  "createdAt": "2021-08-11T04:43:07.786Z",
  "updatedAt": "2021-08-11T04:43:07.786Z"
};

function tranferType(data) {
  return {
    "code": String(data.code),
    "displayOrder": Number(data.displayOrder),
    "name": String(data.name),
    "version": Number(data.version),
    "isActive": Boolean(data.isActive),
    "createdAt": new Date(data.createdAt),
    "updatedAt": new Date(data.updatedAt)
  };
}

var newData = tranferType(originData);
console.log(newData);
```

Or set a target type object first, then convert by each property:

```js
var originData = {
  "code": "00001",
  "displayOrder": "1",
  "name": "Hello",
  "version": "0",
  "isActive": "true",
  "createdAt": "2021-08-11T04:43:07.786Z",
  "updatedAt": "2021-08-11T04:43:07.786Z"
};


let dataTartgetType = {
  "code": "string",
  "displayOrder": "number",
  "name": "string",
  "version": "number",
  "isActive": "boolean",
  "createdAt": "Date",
  "updatedAt": "Date"
}

function transferByType(targetType, data){
  switch(targetType){
    case "string":
      return String(data);
    case "number":
      return  Number(data);
    case "boolean":
      return Boolean(data);
    case "Date":
      return new Date(data);
  }
}

function tranferType2(data){
  let keys = Object.keys(data);
  let newData = {};
  keys.forEach(function(key){
    newData[key] = transferByType(dataTartgetType[key], originData[key])
  });
  return newData;
}


var newData = tranferType2(originData);
console.log(newData);
```

Hope the answer can help you!